# How to check mulitple input fields have values in it using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 input fields 3 are select and 2 are input type and 1 submit button.
i want to enable the submit button when all the fields have value in it.
If any of the value is missing button should go disable again like & condition

**following is my code**

```
<select class='form-control class-manufacturer' name="" id='id_manufacturer>
        <option value="" selected disabled>Manufacturer *</option>
        <option value="">Apple</option>
        <option value="">Samsung</option>
</select>
<select class='form-control class-modelName' name="" id='id_modelName">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Model *</option>
        <option value="" >Iphone</option>
        <option value="" >Note</option>
</select>
<select class='form-control class-partName' name="" id='id_partName' >
        <option value="" selected disabled>Part *</option>
        <option value="" >IC</option>
        <option value="">LED</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name='' id="id_quantity" class="form-control class-quantity" pattern="^[0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="11" placeholder="Quantity *"/>
<input type="text" name='' id="id_costPerUnit" class="form-control class-costPerUnit" pattern="^[0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="11" placeholder="Price *"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-row a"  onclick="add()" disabled='disabled' style="padding:10px 65px;">Add</button>
```

I want to enable and disable the addrow button if all the fields have values using jquery

what i have tried

```
<!--add button disable enable function-->
$(function(){
 var i;
$('.class-manufacturer').change(function(){
$('.class-modelName').change(function() {
$('.class-partName').change(function(){

$('.class-quantity').keypress(function() {
$('.class-costPerUnit').keypress(function(){

$('.add-row').prop('disabled', false);
}); }); }); }); });
 });
```

Comment: and what is it that you've tried with which you want help for

Comment: Use jquery validation plugin or validate simply in if else and then enable / submit your form.

Comment: can you give me code

Comment: <!--add button disable enable function-->
   $(function(){
   var i;
  $('.class-manufacturer').change(function(){
  $('.class-modelName').change(function() {
  $('.class-partName').change(function(){

  $('.class-quantity').keypress(function() {
  $('.class-costPerUnit').keypress(function(){

   $('.add-row').prop('disabled', false);
    }); }); }); }); });
  });

Comment: Refer this doc...https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: not working nitin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $(document).on('keyup change', 'form', function(){
  // Loop through all elements of form
  $.each($('form').find(':input'), function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
      // If any value is empty, disable button and break the loop
      $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      return false;
    }
  })
  // Else if all are filled
  $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var $classmanufacturer = $('.classmanufacturer');
var $classmodelName = $('.classmodelName');
var $classpartName = $('.classpartName');
var $classquantity = $('.classquantity');
var $classcostPerUnit = $('.classcostPerUnit');
var $addbtn = $('.addbtn')
  $('select, input').on('change keypress', function(){
    if(($classmanufacturer.val() != '') && ($classmodelName != '') && ($classpartName.val() != '') && ($classquantity.val() != '') && ($classcostPerUnit.val() != '')){
        $addbtn.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $addbtn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  })
})

function add() {
  alert("enabled");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='form-control classmanufacturer' name="" id='id_manufacturer'>
        <option value="">Manufacturer *</option>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
</select>
<select class='form-control classmodelName' name="" id="id_modelName">
        <option value="">Model *</option>
        <option value="Iphone" >Iphone</option>
        <option value="Note" >Note</option>
</select>
<select class='form-control classpartName' name="" id='id_partName' >
        <option value="">Part *</option>
        <option value="IC" >IC</option>
        <option value="LED">LED</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name='' id="id_quantity" class="form-control classquantity" pattern="^[0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="11" placeholder="Quantity *"/>
<input type="text" name='' id="id_costPerUnit" class="form-control classcostPerUnit" pattern="^[0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="11" placeholder="Price *"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-row a addbtn"  onclick="add()" disabled='disabled' style="padding:10px 65px;">Add</button>
```

Comment: it working but when i remove any value from it should disable again  . i want solution like & state

Comment: i have ajax call to select the drop of selecr

Comment: response from ajax is object or array

Answer (score 0):

Add this **HTML**

```
<input type="submit" id="addRow" value="addRow" disabled="disabled" />
```

Use this `js` code

```
$(function() {
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {

        var checkEmpty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                checkEmpty = true;
            }
        });

        if (checkEmpty ) {
            $('#addRow').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
        } else {
            $('#addRow').removeAttr('disabled'); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

```
$(document).on('keyup change', 'form', function(){
  // Loop through all elements of form
  $.each($('form').find(':input'), function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
      // If any value is empty, disable button and break the loop
      $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      return false;
    }
  })
  // Else if all are filled
  $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that each option in your selectboxes have no value.

You can easily bind the input event on each element having the class form-control to determine the disabled state.

Use this code:

```
function checkForm() {
    var disable = false;
    $(".form-control").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (!value) {
            disable = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("button.add-row").prop("disabled", disable);
}

$(function() {
    $(".form-control").on("input", checkForm);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide a value at `value` attribute of `<option>` elements `html` a that is not an empty string.

You can set `<select>`, `<input>` elements as child nodes of `<form>` element, include `required` attribute at elements, use `input` event attached to `form`, call `.checkValidity()` at `if` condition, if `true` call `.removeAttribute()` on `.btn` element with `"disabled"` as parameter, else call `.setAttribute()` with `"disabled"` as both first and second paramter

```js
document.querySelector("form[name=form]")
.oninput = function() {
    if (this.checkValidity()) {
      this.querySelector(".btn")
      .removeAttribute("disabled")
    } else {
      this.querySelector(".btn")
      .setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <select class='form-control class-manufacturer' name="" id='id_manufacturer' required>
        <option value="" selected disabled>Manufacturer *</option>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
</select>

  <select class='form-control class-modelName' name="" id="id_modelName" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled>Model *</option>
        <option value="Iphone">Iphone</option>
        <option value="Note">Note</option>
</select>

  <select class='form-control class-partName' name="" id='id_partName' required>
        <option value="" selected disabled>Part *</option>
        <option value="IC" >IC</option>
        <option value="LED">LED</option>
</select>
  <input type="text" name='quantity' id="id_quantity" class="form-control class-quantity" pattern="[0-9]{1,}" maxlength="11" placeholder="Quantity *" required/>
  <input type="text" name='cost' id="id_costPerUnit" class="form-control class-costPerUnit" pattern="[0-9]{1,}" maxlength="11" placeholder="Price *" required/>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-row a" onclick="alert('valid')" style="padding:10px 65px;" disabled>Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `required` attribute at `<select>`, `<input>` elements, `:invalid`, `:valid` `css` pseudo class selectors, set `pointer-events` property of `<button>` element to `none` if `form` is invalid or `all` if valid

```css
form:invalid button.btn {
  pointer-events: none;
}

form:valid button.btn {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <select class='form-control class-manufacturer' name="" id='id_manufacturer' required>
        <option value="" selected disabled>Manufacturer *</option>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
</select>

  <select class='form-control class-modelName' name="" id="id_modelName" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled>Model *</option>
        <option value="Iphone">Iphone</option>
        <option value="Note">Note</option>
</select>

  <select class='form-control class-partName' name="" id='id_partName' required>
        <option value="" selected disabled>Part *</option>
        <option value="IC" >IC</option>
        <option value="LED">LED</option>
</select>
  <input type="text" name='quantity' id="id_quantity" class="form-control class-quantity" pattern="[0-9]{1,}" maxlength="11" placeholder="Quantity *" required/>
  <input type="text" name='cost' id="id_costPerUnit" class="form-control class-costPerUnit" pattern="[0-9]{1,}" maxlength="11" placeholder="Price *" required/>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-row a" onclick="alert('valid')" style="padding:10px 65px;" >Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: only css is required ?

Comment: @stone Yes, save for `onclick` attribute event at `html`, which calls `alert()` instead of `add()` at stacksnippets. If `form` is `:invalid` `pointer-events` of `button` element is set to `none` at `css`, else `pointer-events` is set to `all` at `button` element, which permits click on `<button>` element to dispatch `onclick` event at element. See [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid), [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: i have 2 form in page

Comment: but i want use form for 1 form

Comment: @stone Adjust selector at `css` to target appropriate `<form>` element, for example, `form[name="form"]:invalid{pointer-events:none}form[name="form"]:valid{pointer-events:all}`, or use `:nth-of-type()` pseudo class selector to target specific `form` element, if `form` elements do not have unique `.id` or `.className` to select element by. Do both `form` elements have same `.className`?